# Spacing between sections when using UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

**Take a look at this image: http://i41.tinypic.com/2nhizib.png**

My UICollectionView has 3 sections: 1 for data, and 2 more for displaying 2 additional cells. The 2 additional cells displays at a new row in the UICollectionView and I want them to appear continuously with the main cells (continuing to appear after Cell 1 & Cell 2 without getting on a separate row)

*Any idea how I can achieve this?*